# Moving cursor beyond shapes and text boxes I've just inserted

Tags: microsoft-word

I've inserted some shapes and text boxes in the middle of a Word document. I'd like to go back and continue typing in the regular format, but I can't move my cursor beyond the shapes and text boxes I've added.

Comment: *move my cursor beyond the shapes*...do you mean **below**?

Answer (score 0):

After your last paragraph before the shapes, create a space big enough for the shapes to go into and then start typing a new paragraph. You should then be able to move the drawing shape by shape into the gap. Not perfect but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you place the shapes into a "*drawing canvas*"? (e.g: *Insert* → *Shapes* → *New Drawing Canvas*)

If not, then you should be able to double click on any empty portion of the page to continue typing there.

If you did (this is a better solution), then the canvas or image as a whole can be positioned relative to the text. First select the canvas, and then go to *Page Layout* → *Wrap Text* and select an option.

[image: Page Layout, Wrap Text]

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can pick various options.
In your case, you probaly want one of the following:

- In Line with Text
- Square

This will put the canvas or image in-line with the text rather than floating wherever you drop it.